# Easygui output to easygui dialogue?

Tags: python-3.x, easygui

How can I make easygui output to an easygui dialogue, rather than the terminal from which the x.py was invoked.

If I run my python script from a terminal, the easygui dialogue boxes appear and work, but the output is displayed in the terminal and not easygui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
easygui.msgbox('hello world', title='hello world', ok_button = 'yes')
```

that is a way to out put easygui msg

Answer (score 1):

The results need to be passed into the easygui syntax from a pre-declared variable. For example...

```
somemsg = "Some message"
sometitle = "Some title"
someresult = "Some result or text to include in easygui frame"

easygui.textbox(msg=somemsg, title=sometitle, text=someresult)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from easygui import *

name = "josh"
image = "gfg.png"
message = ("hello, my name is",name)

msgbox(message)
textbox(message)
input = buttonbox("message",image = image,choices=("hello","goodbye"))
```

i have not had to use any other easygui boxes at all, except enterbox.

msgbox outputs a simple, small message

textbox is used for larger outputs

buttonbox gives the option for input in response to the output. it also allows the output of images.